# Selenium Java - How to search and find specific nested element given parent elements are the same

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

Suppose I have a page like this:

```
<div class = "A">
   <h1>AA</h1>
   <p>This</p>
</div>

<div class = "A">
   <h1>BB</h1>
   <p>This</p>
</div>
```

And suppose that this goes on for variable lengths, so each time you load the page there is a random number of "class A" divs in a random order with the h1 being: "CC", "DD", etc... How do I find and click on the link "This" that is in the div with the "BB." This is what I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='BB']")).findElement(By.xpath("//*
[text()='This']")).click();
```

I have also tried:

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='BB']"));
name.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='This']")).click();
```

But in both cases I always end up click on the "This" in the div with the "AA." I could define it to clicking the second div, but what if next time I load the page and it randomizes the order so that first and second div switch places. In this case hardcoding it to always click on the second element won't work.

So I would like to know how to search within the div given that condition "BB" exists is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is :

- Get the all "A" class elements in a list.
- Look for header text containing "BB"
- If so then get the tag p of that class "A" index
- Click on "This"

Below is the complete implementation of this.

```
List<WebElement> allClass = driver.findElements(By.className("A"));
    String optionString = "BB"; 

    for(WebElement elm : allClass){
        WebElement header = elm.findElement(By.tagName("h1"));
        if(header.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(optionString)){
            WebElement thisP = elm.findElement(By.tagName("p"));
            thisP.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked. All I had to do was add another if statement after thisP to check if the text of "this" matches

Answer (score 0):

To find and click on the link `This` which is in the div with the `BB` you can use the following code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='A']/h1[text()='BB']//following::p[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
//div[@class='A']//h1[text()='BB']//following::p
```

OR

```
//div[contains(@class,'A')]//h1[text()='BB']//following::p
```

Code:

```
WebElement thisClick= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'A')]//h1[text()='BB']//following::p"));
thisClick.findElement(By.xpath("p[text()=='This']")).click();
```